# All possible matrices of order n with entries from a range in python

Tags: python, matrix

I want to write a function where given the two integers "n" and "p", it puts all the possible matrices of order n where the elements come from {0,1,...,p-1} into a set.

for example : for `n=2` and `p=2`
we have:

```
[[0,0],[0,0]] , 

[[1,1],[1,1]] ,

[[1,0],[0,0]] , 

[[0,1],[0,0]] , 

[[0,0],[1,0]] , 

[[0,0],[0,1]] , 

[[1,1],[0,0]] , 

[[0,0],[1,1]] , 

[[1,1],[1,0]] , 

[[1,0],[1,1]] , 

[[1,1],[0,1]] , 

[[0,1],[1,1]] ,

[[0,1],[0,1]] , 

[[1,0],[1,0]] , 

[[0,1],[1,0]] , 

[[1,0],[0,1]]
```

I later want to check a condition for determinant of each matrix and only accept the ones with determinant equal to 1 or 0.

I couldn't find any functions in numpy to do the trick. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @Chris I got this idea and it does the job. 
the problem with Chris's answer was it would only generate 2*2 matrices and all my attempts to fix that failed as I already mentioned them in the comment.

```
x = [y for y in range(p)]
a=[j for j in product(x, repeat=n)]
b={k for k in product(a, repeat=n)}
```

Comment: @Itamar Mushkin I tried to do so but it seems like I cant accept my own answer in two days.

Answer (score 2):

Itertools permutations is great for this.  The first permutation line will generate a list of tuples containing every 2 number combo from your two ranges.  There will be duplicates in this, which you can verify by printing `l` and seeing for yourself.

You can take these tuples and create pairs of combos with them, removing duplicates with the `set` function, resulting in 16 combinations in this example.

```
from itertools import permutations
n = 2
p = 2

l = list(permutations([x for x in range(n)]+[y for y in range(p)],2))

set(permutations(l,2))
```

Output

```
{((0, 0), (0, 0)),
 ((0, 0), (0, 1)),
 ((0, 0), (1, 0)),
 ((0, 0), (1, 1)),
 ((0, 1), (0, 0)),
 ((0, 1), (0, 1)),
 ((0, 1), (1, 0)),
 ((0, 1), (1, 1)),
 ((1, 0), (0, 0)),
 ((1, 0), (0, 1)),
 ((1, 0), (1, 0)),
 ((1, 0), (1, 1)),
 ((1, 1), (0, 0)),
 ((1, 1), (0, 1)),
 ((1, 1), (1, 0)),
 ((1, 1), (1, 1))}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. I need to get n*n matrices but when i input `n=3` and `p=2` I get the same result as `n=2` and `p=3` which is all the 2*2 matrices with {0,1,2}. so i tried to change your code a bit, my first attempt was to change the two `2` in you permutations to    `n` but it didn't work so i tried using `combinations_with_replacement()` instead of `permutations()` and the second argument to `n` and a deleted the `[x for x in range(n)]+` part and it still didn't work properly. i get the n*n matrices the second way but they are not the correct number.